# no wifi on windows 10 media creation tool

Tags: networking, wireless-networking, windows-10

I was tired of waiting for the windows 10 download so went ahead and downloaded the media creation tool from windows site but now i can't search wifi or change wifi settings because it is not there. I am running a Lenovo edge 15 bought it about 2 or 3 months ago, i7 samsung ssd, all the drivers i tried updating but they say they are up to date. tried disabling and enabling. i tried custom install and express install. I even tried plugging an ethernet cable in and still there is no internet connection to the laptop. If i revert back to windows 8.1 the problem goes away.

Comment: Do you have the old legacy Cisco VPN installed? You'll have to revert to 8.1 and uninstall it there. I wasn't able to uninstall it once I upgraded to windows 10. See my answer in [here](http://superuser.com/questions/947651/no-network-connection-after-upgrading-to-windows-10)

Comment: Now what if i use the cisco vpn for school, will I be able to reinstall it on windows 10?

Comment: If it's the old legacy one no, and you don't want to, it's really bad. You can use Shrew Soft VPN Client. If you have a .pcf file you use with the Cisco client you can just import it and use it. Shew Soft doesn't install the network filters and crap that the old Cisco client does. You could also use their new Cisco Anyconnect, but I really just recommend Shrew Soft's.

Comment: My school only provides the cisco vpn but I have a few others

Comment: The solution I was faced with was to setup another drive and boot ubuntu on that and then install vpnc and vpn to school through there and create an ssh file to speed the process