# WIndows 10 refuses to connect to Internet

Tags: windows-10

Full disclosure - my software knowledge is pretty basic, but I usually manage our little home network just fine, but I'm no expert.
Wife just upgraded to Windows 10. Mostly painless update, but now her computer will not connect to the internet. 
It is not a modem or router issue. 
Yes, the cables are good. 
The error appears to be a bad IP configuration, but I can't find out where it's configured. It keeps trying to default the connection to a VPN, when it's not.
It won't even find the modem address.

Comment: possible duplicate of [No network connection after upgrading to Windows 10](http://superuser.com/questions/947651/no-network-connection-after-upgrading-to-windows-10)

Comment: Had the same problem. After the upgrade, the internet through Wifi was working but the internet through ethernet cable was not working (bad ip error). After an update of the required driver from the manufacturer site (Intel in my case), the error has disappeared and everything is fine.

Comment: Do you use AVG Anti Virus? If so, try disabling it.

Comment: this a wired only PC, no Wifi to work from. Already tried reverting back to win 8 - did not fix the issue.

Comment: also i dont work with a VPN, so that is NOT THE ISSUE. Had both my ISP and Windows Tech tell me it was a VPN issue.

Answer (score 0):

You can try these steps:

1.Go back to your old windows (eg. Window 8)

2.Uninstall the VPN Client,

3.Upgrade again

Links: https://superuser.com/a/947695/476132